# ANGULAR 8 Assets files not being served

Tags: angular

Some files that i upload with express-fileupload or i create files, i can see the in the assets folder and they work but when i try  to open it, in the explorer i get not found.

I dont know why is the problem.

here is an example:
file not found
Request URL:http://localhost:4200/assets/68.pdf
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found

here is the code, the upload of the file works but i can see the image taht i upload in the explorer

```
router.post("", function(req, res){
    console.log('body', req.body); 
    console.log(req.files);
    if(req.files){
        var file = req.files.file;
        var filename = file.name; 
        file.mv('src/assets/' + filename, function (err){
            if(err){
                return res.status(500).json({message:'Se presento un problema al subir el archivo'});
            } else 
            {
                    res.status(200).json(data);
            }
        })
          

    }
    
})
```

some files thar i copy or create inside assets i can see them in the explorer but the files that i upload o or some that i create i can see them.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start `ng serve`, the assets are cached and so you will not see new images until you restart `ng serve`.

You should upload the files to a different folder and serve the files from that folder with a proper webserver